# Property 'events' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I have this method where I use FullCalendar to load events, but I keep getting error:

> error TS2339: Property 'events' does not exist on type 'Object'.

This is my method:

```
loadInfo() {
this.userService.getChallengesByUserId(2).then(data => {
  this.userChallenges = data;
  this.userChallenges.forEach(ch => {
    var obj = {
      id: ch.challengeId,
      title: 'plz work'.toString(),
      start: ch.startDate,
      end: ch.endDate
    };
    this.calendarEvents.push(obj);
  });
  this.calendarOptions.events = this.calendarEvents;
  $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.calendarEvents, true);
});
```

}

And this is calendarOptions:

```
calendarOptions: Object = {
height: 'parent',
header: {
  left: 'title',
  center: '',
  right: 'today prev,next'
},
//  fixedWeekCount: false,
defaultDate: Date.now(),
editable: false,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
views: {
  month: {
    eventLimit: 5
  }
},
eventClick: this.alertOnEventClick,
events: []
```

};

Even though when I print `console.log(this.calendarOptions)` I can see that `events` exist there

Comment: move the `calendarOptions` initialization to the constructor and try again

Comment: Declare the type of `calendarOptions` as `any` e.g `calendarOptions:any` or simply `calendarOptions` , remove the `Object` type because `event` is not a known property of javascript `Object`

Comment: Check this link for the difference between Object vs {} in typescript https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type#object-vs-object-vs